# Anime where the protagonist fixes old airship

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this Japanese anime a while back (about 2013-2015) so bear with me on the details. I cant remember if it was new at the time or a little bit older. I think I watched it on Crunchyroll.

The show was about the main character trying to put together this old airship that’s near these dragon bones or something, and it details his struggle trying to fix this and being the captain of it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch it?  "A while back" isn't very specific.  Where did you see it, and in what language?

Comment: It was a Japanese anime and a while back would roughly be 2013-2015, I cant remember if it was new at the time or a little bit older. I think I watched it on crunchyroll.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was [*Granblue Fantasy The Animation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granblue_Fantasy_The_Animation), a friend of mine got back to me and told me the answer.